# ASP.NET MVC HTML.Beginform is not calling the right action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am well aware that there are similar question to my question but it they does not answer my question properly.

My main problem is that whenever I click the update button in my view this is where it brings me to

```
https://localhost:44332/Clique/AdminDashboard?Start=2021-07-21&End=2021-07-20
```

but I want it to take me to

```
https://localhost:44332/Clique/UpdateTotalServed?Start=2021-07-21&End=2021-07-20
```

Here is the code of my back-end

```
public ActionResult AdminDashboard()
{
    QTableEntities db = new QTableEntities();

    return View(db.QTables.ToList());
}

public ActionResult UpdateTotalServed(DateTime Start, DateTime End)
{
    QTableEntities db = new QTableEntities();

    var a = db.QTables.Where(x => x.QDate > Start).ToList();
    var b = a.Where(x => x.QDate < End).ToList();

    return View("AdminDashboard", b);
}
```

and here is the code of my front-end

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateTotalServed", "Clique", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <br><label for="">FROM</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Start", null, new { type = "date" })
    <label for="">TO</label>
    @Html.TextBox("End", null, new { type = "date" })
    <input type="submit" , class="btn btn-month-year" value="UPDATE" />
}
```

GOT my answers:
I had

Comment: Just to clarify, your controller action UpdateTotalServed does not get hit?

Comment: The codes are incomplete. I suggest creating a project and push it to GitHub to illustrate the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you post the whole view , pls, not just a part

Comment: @RobWhite yup that is correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing

```
[HttpPost]
```

attribute on your update method

Comment: already thought about this but still does not work.